# How do I make this flat array hierarchical in PHP without parent IDs?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a flat array structure (`$rows`) with an array of columns (`$groupByCols`) that I want to group the data by:

```
$groupByCols = ['a', 'b'];
$rows = [
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 10,
        'c' => 100
    ],
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 20,
        'c' => 200
    ],
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 20,
        'c' => 300
    ],
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 30,
        'c' => 400
    ],
    [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 40,
        'c' => 500
    ],
    [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 50,
        'c' => 600
    ],
    [
        'a' => 3,
        'b' => 60,
        'c' => 700
    ]
];
```

By looping through the `$rows` variable and referencing each of the `$groupByCols` values in order, I want to get the following hierarchical array:

```
$groupedRows = [
    [
        [
            [
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 10,
                'c' => 100
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 20,
                'c' => 200
            ],
            [
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 20,
                'c' => 300
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 30,
                'c' => 400
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [
                'a' => 2,
                'b' => 40,
                'c' => 500
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                'a' => 2,
                'b' => 50,
                'c' => 600
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [
                'a' => 3,
                'b' => 60,
                'c' => 700
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm 99% sure that I need to use recursion for this, but after trying about 10 different things (none of which worked), I can't figure out how to get what I want.

Normally, I would share code I've written thus far, but after thinking about this for several days and not getting anywhere, I really don't have much to show.

I think I just need some general guidance on how I can (assumingly) recursively use the `$groupByCols` and `$rows` variables to get the `$groupedRows` array. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Also, please note that the data above is very simple for demonstration purposes. The real data can be infinity longer and more complex, and I may have to go down 5-6 levels with the `$groupByCols`, depending on the nature of what's required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will do what you want. It goes through the array, grouping by the values indexed by the first value in `$columns`. If there are columns remaining in the `$columns` array, it recursively groups by those columns. To avoid having oddly numbered keys, it calls `array_values` to reindex the result to numeric keys starting at 0.

```
function group_by($array, $columns) {
    $new_arr = array();
    $column = array_shift($columns);
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        $new_arr[$arr[$column]][] = $arr;
    }
    if (count($columns)) {
        foreach ($new_arr as &$arr) {
            $arr = group_by($arr, $columns);
        }
    }
    return array_values($new_arr);
}
print_r(group_by($rows, $groupByCols));
```

Output is as you desire, but rather than clutter the answer with a long print, just see the demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JP2ee).

Comment: That's great, Nick. Thank you! You know, on one of my attempts, I actually had something really close to that, and I didn't realize that I was almost there. The main thing I was missing was the `&` to reference the array. Darn! Thanks again though. A life-saver!